# How to disable a UIButton for 3 seconds?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Big edit: I'm a complete begginer to Obj-C and iOS development.

When my UIButton is pressed, a label with fade in. This label takes 3 seconds to do fade in. How would I go about disabling the UIButton for those 3 seconds?

This is what I was trying:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f animations:^{
    self.button.enabled = NO;
    self.quoteLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
    self.quoteLabel.text = self.quotes.randomQuote;
    self.labelForNumberOfTimesRead.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+ %d",numberOfTimesRead ];

}];
self.button.enabled = YES;
```

But it only disables for an 'instant'.

Comment: Set `enabled = NO` on the button before showing the label. When the animation is done, set it back to `YES`.

Comment: To further elaborate, use animateWithDuration:animations:completion: to do the animation, set enabled to NO before you call it, and then back to YES in the completion block.

Comment: @rdelmar tried that as well but it didn't work. I'm trying to figure out how to use NSTimer as rmaddy suggested.

Comment: You didn't do it correctly. Set it to no before calling the animation, and set it to YES in the completion block -- you're using the shorter method that doesn't use a completion block, so the last statement will execute immediately after you start the animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply like this,

```
self.button.enabled = NO;
self.quoteLabel.text = self.quotes.randomQuote;
self.labelForNumberOfTimesRead.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+ %d",numberOfTimesRead ];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3 animations:^{
        self.quoteLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            self.button.enabled = YES;
        }
         ];
```

It's not clear what you're doing with labelForNumberOfTimesRead. Do you want that one to fade in (or out) as well?

Comment: Nope, that one would always be showing. It's a label next to a button which when clicked will show a random quote. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have put some code so we could help you better. For now I am adding psudocode .You can use NSTimer here .

1. add `[yourButton setEnable : NO]` on the click of your button .
2. And when your animation completes then add `[yourButton setEnable : YES]`.
3. If you face any difficulty for getting the animation complete event then  you can use the NSTimer also.

Comment: Sorry for not putting the code up, what I had tried was just that:    `[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f animations:^{
        self.button.enabled = NO;
        self.quoteLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
        self.quoteLabel.text = self.quotes.randomQuote;
        self.labelForNumberOfTimesRead.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+ %d",numberOfTimesRead ];
    }];
    self.button.enabled = YES;`

Comment: That it doesn't work. It runs right through so it is only disabled for an instant. And sorry for my horrible 'mini-markdown', trying to fix..

Comment: On button click try to add NSTimer of 3 sec and disable button and enable it again in timer callback

Comment: thank you! the animation method worked. It was just that I was using a shorter version. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Start by disabling the button
self.button.enabled = NO;

// This method will **queue** an animation but it won't start right away
[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f animations:^{

    // Next animate anything you want
    self.quoteLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
    self.quoteLabel.text = self.quotes.randomQuote;
    self.labelForNumberOfTimesRead.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+ %d",numberOfTimesRead ];

}
// Use completion block to re-enable button
completion:^(BOOL finished){
    self.button.enabled = YES;
}
];

// The following line is commented as it would be executed before the animation block!
// self.button.enabled = YES;
```